# convolution and integral limits

Tags: integration, analysis, convolution

Let $\xi$ be an increasing function , and $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$. Take $\phi$ a smooth function such that $\int_0^1 \phi(s)\, ds= 1 $ and consider an approximation of identity $\phi_n(s) = n \phi(ns)$. define $\xi^n(s) = \xi*\phi_n(s)$ (the convolution with $\phi_n$) Is is true that $$\int f(x) \, d\xi(x) = \lim_n \int f(x) \, d\xi^n(x).$$

**ps:**  could $\xi$ be arbitrary?

Answer (score 2):

It's true if $\xi$ is continuous at $0$ and $1$. Alternatively, it's true for arbitrary $\xi$ if we restrict to $f$ with $f(0)=0=f(1)$.

I'm assuming here that $\xi$ is defined on $\mathbb R$, so that the convolution is *defined*. If $\xi$ is originally defined only on $[0,1]$ you can extend it.

There's a simple proof if you know about Schwarz functions and tempered distributions. There exists a positive measure $\mu$ such that $$\int f\,d\xi=\int f\,d\mu.$$This $\mu$ satisfies $$\mu=D\xi$$in the sense of distributions. Hence $$D\xi^n=D(\xi*\phi_n)=(D\xi)*\phi_n=\mu*\phi_n,$$so that $\mu*\phi_n$ is the measure corresponding to $\xi^n$: $$\int f\,d\xi^n=\int f\,d(\mu*\phi_n).$$

Now, $\mu*\phi_n\to\mu$ in the weak* topology of $C_c(\mathbb R)^*$. This shows that $$\int f\,d\xi^n\to\int f\,d\xi\quad(f\in C_c(\mathbb R)).$$Which is not quite what you asked about.

Suppose that $f\in C([0,1])$ *and* $f(0)=0=f(1)$. Then $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ which has compact support contained in $[0,1]$. Hence $$\int_0^1f\,d\xi^n\to\int_0^1f\,d\xi\quad(f\in C([0,1]),f(0)=0=f(1)).$$That's the second of the two claims I made at the top.

Finally, since the formula holds for all $f\in C([0,1])$ with $f(0)=0=f(1)$, it follows that it holds for *all* $f\in C([0,1])$ if and only if it holds for $f(t)=1$ and $f(t)=t$. Which you easily verify directly, *if* $\xi$ is continuous at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thank you @David C. Ullrich , but  why $\int_0^1 f\, d \xi^n \to \int_0^1 f\, d\xi$ (f \in C_c(\Bbb{R})) and what is the claim you claim is your second claim?

Comment: The "second claim" is the statement that it holds for all $\xi$ if $f(0)=0=f(1)$. Suppose so. We can regard $f$ as an element of $C_c(\mathbb R)$ which vanishes outside $[-K,K]$. So $\int_0^1f\,d\xi^n=\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\mu_n=\int_{\mathbb R}f\,d\mu_n\to\int_Rf\,d\mu=\int_{[0,1]}f\,d\mu=\int_0^1f\,d\xi$. Here $\mu_n=\mu*\phi_n$.

Comment: But why $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\, d\xi^n\to \int_{\Bbb{R}}f \, d\xi$?

Comment: That holds for $f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ because $\mu_n=\mu*\phi_n\to\mu$ weak* in $C_c(\mathbb R)^*$.

Comment: But why $\mu_n \to \mu$ weak*?

Comment: I was taking that as well known. Say $f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$. Say $g(t)=f(-t)$. Then $g*\phi_n\to g$ uniformly (yes?). Hence $(g*\phi_n)*\mu\to g*\mu$ pointwise. Hence $g*\mu_n\to g*\mu$ pointwise. But (if I got the details straight, if not you can fix) $g*\mu_n(0)=\int f\,d\mu_n$ and similarly $g*\mu(0)=\int f\,d\mu$.

Comment: $g*\phi_n \to g$ uniformly is ok. I understand that $f * \mu(x) := \int f(x-y)\, d\mu(y)$ (is it right?). then I can see that $(g* \phi_n)*\mu to g * \mu$ pointwise. But why $g*\mu_n \to g*\mu$ pointwise? that is, why $$\int g(x-y)\, d(\phi_n*\mu)(y) \to \int g(x-y)\, d\mu(y).$$Yet another question Is $\mu_n = \phi_n*\mu $ or is $\mu_n(f) := \int f*\phi_n \, d\mu$? or are they equivalent?

Comment: Convolution is associative. $(g*\phi_n)*\mu=g*(\phi_n*\mu)=g*\mu_n$. I said $\mu_n=\phi_n*\mu$. That's not quite equivalent to the other, just because $h*\mu(0)=\int h(-t)\,d\mu(t)$, not just $\int h\,d\mu$. That's why we introduced the function $g$.

Comment: I understand, still I would like to know why $(g*\phi_n)*\mu = g*(\phi_n*\mu)$. Do you think this is a separate question?

Comment: Write down the definitions of both sides...

Comment: $$(g*\phi_n)*\mu(x) = \int g* \phi_n(x-y)\, d\mu(y)=\int \int g(x-y-z)\phi_n(z)\, dz \, d\mu(y)\\g*(\phi_n*\mu)(x) = \int g(x-z)\, \phi_n*\mu(z)\, dz = \int \int g(x-z)\phi_n(z-y) \, d\mu(y) \, dz$$ then we change variables $z = z-y$ on the first equation and we obtain $$(g*\phi_n)*\mu(x)=\int g* \phi_n(x-y)\, d\mu(y)=\int\int g(x-z)\phi_n(z-y)\, dz\,d\mu(y)\\g*(\phi_n*\mu)(x) = \int g(x-z)\, \phi_n*\mu(z)\,dz=\int \int g(x-z)\phi_n(z-y)\,d\mu(y)\,dz$$ therefore equality follows, Still I don't understand why $$\int f(-y)\,d(\phi_n*\mu)(y) =\int f(-y)(\phi_n*\mu)(y)\, dy$$ we used it didn't we?

Comment: Suppose $\psi$ is a function and $\nu$ is a measure. Then you can define a new measure $\lambda$ by $d\lambda=\psi\,d\nu$, which is to say $\lambda(E)=\int_E\psi\,d\nu$. It follows that $\int g\,d\lambda=\int g\psi\,d\nu$. (And when $\nu$ is Lebesgue measure we sometimes identify $\lambda$ and $\psi$, referring to $\psi$ as though it were the measure $\lambda$ and vice versa.)

Comment: Are you saying that for $\lambda = \phi_n* d\mu$ $\lambda(E) = \int \phi_n *\mu (y)\, dy$? why is this true? I only found that $\int_0^t d(\phi_n* \xi) = \phi_n *\xi(t) - \phi_n *\xi(0)$ when the integral is taken in the stieltjes sense but I am stuck here

Comment: No, I never wrote $\phi_n*d\mu$. I believe the a=bc=d at the start of your question was meant to be two separate equations, a=b,  c=d. If so the second equation is one of the things I'm saying, yes, except you left out the _E. And in the equation after the words "I only found that" I believe that you meant $\phi_n*\xi$ in place of $\phi_nn\xi$. If so then yes, that equals what you said. Now insert the definition of $\phi_n*\xi$ in both places and see what happens.

Comment: This really seems like it's not going to end - the fact that we're getting to a point where I'm not sure whether something you write is a typo or not doesn't help. So I end it, sorry.